# Why sys.dm_fts_parser is not accent sensitive on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

1. Run the statement on SQL Server 2014:

```
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'français', 1036, 0, 1)
```

The result is: 'français' which is correct because I specified accent sensitive flag = 1

2. Run the same statement on SQL Server 2008 Standard edition server:

```
SELECT display_term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'français', 1036, 0, 1)
```

The result is: 'francais'  which is incorrect because I specified accent sensitive flag = 1

So, on SQL Server 2008 always the display_term is returned without accents!
I've tested on multiple 2008 instances.

Why? This is an unexpected behavior and I have no clue about it (maybe some database collation but it should not because I given an unicode input)

Comment: Why are you asking about a version that's already out of support? In fact, both versions are out of mainstream support, [SQL Server 2008 has reached End-Of-Life](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456242/end-of-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2) (ie no support unless you pay MS for specific fixes). It's quite possible this was a bug that was fixed in the 6 years between 2008 and 2014

Comment: As an FYI, I can't replicate this on SQL Server 2012, so perhaps it really is a case of use supported software.

Comment: Unfortunately we have SQLServer2008 in production. And i dont know if it will be upgraded very soon. I made the development on SQL2014 and when i deployed in production SURPRISE! it doesn't works on accents

Comment: Anyway .. is there any other method to split a phrase in words based on language specific words breaker ?